# Three.js - Using an SVG texture on SphereGeometry?

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, svg, three.js

I've been following the tutorial here:  http://www.delimited.io/blog/2015/5/16/interactive-webgl-globes-with-threejs-and-d3

This example uses a Canvas element and then wraps this as a texture to the THREE SphereGeometry. I wasn't happy with how blurry the lines were rendering so opted to render as an SVG. The SVG path data is being constructed by D3 and topojson.

My question is this: can I translate this SVG data to a SphereGeometry texture? I'd like to be able to zoom and retain detail on the final object - if there's a way to do this with canvas I'd also be interested.

Here's my code that draws the SVG;

```
var width = 1024,
    height = 512;

var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
     .scale(163)
     .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
     .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);

d3.json("data/world.json", function(err, data) {
svg.append("path")
     .datum(topojson.feature(data,data.objects.countries))
     .attr("d", path)
     .attr("class", "countries");
```

Comment: Did you find answer for this question later? I'm having the same question now